# Pasar a otro layout después de un Login correcto con OAuth2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, login, oauth

Estoy desarrollando una App `Android` con `Android Studio` y la primera página que quiero salga es la de autenticación OAuth2.0 de Google, y que si el `login` es correcto me salte a otro `layout` distinto con funcionalidades distintas.

Mi duda es:

**¿Dónde debería incluir esas líneas de código y como se hace?**

os dejo el Login.java que es donde debería incluir esa redirección a otro `layout`:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////    1     /////////////////////////////////////
        // [START configure_signin]
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END configure_signin]

        //////////////////////////////////////////////    2     /////////////////////////////////////
        // [START build_client]
        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        // [END build_client]

        //////////////////////////////////////////////    OPCIONAL     /////////////////////////////////////
        // [START customize_button]
        // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
        // SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        // signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        // [END customize_button]

        //////////////////////////////////////////////    3     /////////////////////////////////////
        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        // findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        // findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        /* OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        } */
    }

    // [START onActivityResult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////    6     /////////////////////////////////////
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    // [END onActivityResult]

    //////////////////////////////////////////////    7     /////////////////////////////////////
    // [START handleSignInResult]
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
           // mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    // [END handleSignInResult]

    //////////////////////////////////////////////    5     /////////////////////////////////////
    // [START signIn]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signIn]

    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            //mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            /*case R.id.sign_out_button:
                signOut();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                revokeAccess();
                break;*/
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lanza la nueva `Activity` en el método `handleSignInResult`. Puedes sustituir `updateIU(true)`por el código para lanzar una nueva `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NombreDeLaSegundaACtivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

En la variable `acct` tienes los datos del usuario. Sería conveniente pasar este `objeto` a la segunda `Activity`

Comment: Es decir la variable acc tiene los datos del usuario con el que se ha hecho el Login verdad? Porque seria conveniente pasar esa variable a la otra activity y como se haria?

Comment: Lo decía porque al realizas el logueo con Google he deducido que es para recoger una cierta información sobre el usuario. Esta información se encuentra en el objeto `acct`. Pero si no lo necesitas no pasa nada. En caso de necesitarlo abre otra pregunta y así mantenemos el foro ordenado. ;-)